Finding the refractive surface from incoming and outgoing directions
Like the title says I am trying to find the angle of a refractive surface using by only knowing the direction of the incoming and outgoing rays, as well as the refractive indices of both mediums. Using snells law, I seem to have narrowed it down to an equation which can be written in many ways, the simplest probably being:
$$n_1 \sin(\theta_1) = n_2 \sin(\theta_2) \Rightarrow  n_1 \sin(\theta_1) = -n_2 \sin(\theta_{io} + \theta_1)  $$
Here $\theta_{io}$ is the smallest angle between the ingoing and outgoing ray, and $\theta_1$ is the angle between the surface normal and the ingoing ray. How to solve this?

Which variable is the unknown here?

It seems I am dumb. I worked the equation further and have seemingly arrived at a solution space
$$
\theta_1 = \arctan\left(\frac{-\eta\cdot\sin\left(\theta_{io}\right)}{1+\eta\cdot\cos\left(\theta_{io}\right)}\right) + n\pi,n \in \mathbb{N}, \eta = \frac{n_2}{n_1}
$$
